# Stories in Hindu scripture on drinking human blood

Tags: mahabharata, practice, symbolism, teaching

1. Kaali drinking blood of Raktabīja.
2. Bheema drinking blood of Dushasana.
3. Draupadi intending to drink blood of Bheema.

What's the intent behind drinking blood?

Comment: You should fix the title of your question so it doesn't sound like an opinion-based question.

Comment: `Drapaudi intending to drink blood of bheem` when?

Comment: I would highly appreciate once you come up with a good research & constructive criticism. Even in any case if you are in Zakir Naik mode ardently, I would suggest you to read basic Hindu philosophies, will at least help you to post a good question.

Comment: @ maniWhat are some lesser known/interesting stories in Mahabharata? by Arthi Chandrasekar https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-lesser-known-interesting-stories-in-Mahabharata/answer/Arthi-Chandrasekar?share=f311db9b&srid=u0HOB

Comment: Even i don't like Bheema drinking blood, that was kind of inhuman but thats the way it is..But Mahakali or Chamunda drinking blood was to save the universe from that powerful demon..

Comment: For (3), there are a billion Hindus, and Hinduism doesn't issue a Fatwa when someone speaks randomly about stories in it. So people misuse their freedom and cook up random stories. There is no point in asking the other (Billion - 1) people about it.

Comment: Daraupadi never drank blood. This is a stupid story concocted by some individuals. It does not feature in the mahabharata. Bheema did not drink Dussasana's blood either according to the original work. Such stories are indeed attractive to the non-hindu and hindu-haters. However, they are patently false.

Comment: @moonstar2001, you are right about Bhima not drinking blood of DushAsana. Found that in the scripture & covered in this post: [What was the real story of Bhima's oath about drinking DushAsana's blood? ...](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19575/1049).

Answer (score 5):

All these examples has nothing to do with Hinduism.

> Kaali drinking blood of raktabija.

Because Raktbija got boon that when even his single drop of blood will fall on earth, then from that Drop another Raktbija(demon/devil) will be created. And death of Raktbija was necessary to save world. Then Mahakali came in front and to avoid any drop of his blood from falling on earth she herself drank his whole blood so more devil's generation can be stopped by his blood.

**NOTE** This action of Mahakali was only to protect mankind from cruelty of Raktbija. Drinking blood was only option to kill him. From where Hinduism came here. This act of Mahakali is directly related with Humanity, not with Hinduism because she did this not only to protect Hindus but to protect all mankind including all religion.

> Bheem drinking blood of dushashana.

Bheem took promise of drinking blood of Dushasan and also swear that he will wash Draupadi's hair with his blood. He did that Promise when Dushasan brought Draupadi in Sabhaa by dragging her by hair.

This Promise/swear of him was the result of his anger, not the result of his teaching of Hinduism. In anger one can't judge good or bad. So you can't match inhuman promise of him with Hinduism.

> Draupadi intending to drink blood of bheem.

I never even heard anything like that.

**To know full detail with references, read [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16531/who-are-chamunda-and-chandika/16536#16536)**

Comment: What are some lesser known/interesting stories in Mahabharata? by Arthi Chandrasekar https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-lesser-known-interesting-stories-in-Mahabharata/answer/Arthi-Chandrasekar?share=f311db9b&srid=u0HOB

Comment: @AbdulMuqitshaik It is a cooked up story by Arthi Chandrashekhar. lesser known to the writer of Mahabharata too.

Comment: You should cite sources. See [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/803) meta post.

Comment: @sv. I don't google for the basic info about Hindu scriptures which is even known to a child. What I have shown in my answer is well known fact of Mahabharat and Kali's war. Every Hindu knows this, hence posted this as an answer. If I am already aware of any fact then Should I need to do google for it first (even if I know the anser) and post links of site. Sorry but I will pass. Anyone here on this site who can proof me wrong regarding my given answer then they are most welcome.

Comment: Rishabh If u want u can take references from my answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16536/4732:

Comment: @rickross I can't understand why they even want reference of a basic Hindu story which are even known to small children!!! It doesn't make any sense. They are just trying to be over smart but they are not.

Comment: @Rishabh You are right about the story being well known but irrespective of whether the stories are well known or less known while writing answers we have to provide sources from scriptures along with them. That's the rule here and we have to follow it.

Comment: @Rickross Alright, I have given the link BUT not all user use to read on internet about Hinduism. My main source of information is TV, not internet. So it's hard to post a link of any site since I don't use internet to learn about Hinduism. I can reference a TV serial if that reference will be valid.