# Relation between Chamunda and Kali

Tags: kali, shaktism, chamunda

Would like to know relation between Chamunda and Kali
In one of [my previous posts](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/31726/5212), @Rickross mentioned Kali having /holding kapala whereas Chamunda **doesn't hold Kapala**.

However, when I talked to persons in my village who are Shakteyas, told me Chamunda is also kind of "flavor"of Kali.

Both are having 3 letters in common : "aim", "hrim",  " klim"
I am surprised, what may be the relationship between these two!

NB: I would love to talk about this "Kapaala" more.

Comment: Not really about the question but when you have found something useful in the comment, ask the users to convert comments to answers so that everyone get to read them. Comments are not for answers. I found one of your posts where you have agreed with the comment but it is still not answered. Please do so. Which previous post are you talking about? Please link it so that users will get idea about the background of the question.

Comment: See this answer .. it answers from the Puranic standpoint: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16536/4732

Comment: Okay, but the Dhyana/Avastha are different for both Chamunda & Kali...

Comment: Yes I have to check that .. need time @SaMolPP

Answer (score 3):

Emergence of Kali was mentioned in [Chapter 7](https://www.templepurohit.com/durga-saptashati/durga-saptashati-chater-7/) of **Durga Saptashati**/Devi Mahatmya.

> ततः कोपं चकारोच्चैरम्बिका तानरीन् प्रति। कोपेन चास्या वदनं
>   मषी*वर्णमभूत्तदा॥५॥
>
> **भ्रुकुटीकुटिलात्तस्या** ललाटफलकाद्द्रुतम्। ***काली*** करालवदना
>   विनिष्क्रान्तासिपाशिनी॥६॥
>
> Thereupon Ambika became **terribly angry** with those foes, and in her
>   anger her countenance then became dark as ink. Out from the surface of
>   her forehead, fierce with frown, suddenly issued **Kali** of terrible
>   countenance, armed with a sword and noose.

After a bitter fight, Kali chops off the heads of Chanda and Munda and brings the same to Chandika.

> Chandika names her ***chAmunda*** for this act.
>
> यस्माच्चण्डं च मुण्डं च गृहीत्वा त्वमुपागता। ***चामुण्डेति*** ततो लोके
>   ख्याता देवि भविष्यसि॥ॐ॥२७॥

---

So chAmunda and kAli are one and the same.  As kAli emerged from Chandika, there is no difference between kAli and Chandika, as the fierce form of Chandika is kAli.

That was why the dhyAna mantra of chandika is

**'ऐं ह्रीं क्लीं चामुंडायै विच्चे'**

---

As per the idols, chAmunda Devi also wears garland of heads of demons.

[image]

[image]